# Is there is any harmful effect if I am using 2 amp instead of 1 amp

Tags: current

for my dish tv set up box. I am using 5 volt 2amp ac/dc adapter instead of 1amp. Is it okay? Or harmful?
That dealer said to me that I can use higher amp. 
Please reply. ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no harmful effect. The load (your set-top box) will draw only as much current as it needs, regardless of how much the power source may have available.

In the same manner that you can plug a 2-watt night-light into a power mains circuit capable of thousands of watts.